# Join query for getting non matching records

Tags: mysql, join, sql-query-store

I have a question regarding MySql statement. I have 2 tables, record and training. Training table contains list of all courses, and record table contains list of courses that the user have attend. Training table is below

[image]

Record table format:

[image]

I want to get list non attending courses of each user. For eg: From the above table structure, user 277 is attending 130,167,128 & 2. So the non attending courses of user 277 is 3,4,5,7,8,9,147,11,12.

How can i write sql statement for getting the above result? Please help

Comment: Which is the foreign key in record table from training table?

Comment: trainingId is the foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its something like this

```
SELECT * FROM training t WHERE t.id NOT IN (select trainingId from record where UserId=277 && piId=1) && t.status=1 ORDER BY t.categoryId
```

Comment: What is wrong with the answers you have already been given. Both mine and the one by @FaizHalde will give you the results you have asked for (mine gives it for all users, which can easily be changed with a WHERE clause if you only want one user, the other answer is specific for one user).

Comment: Yes, i made a little changes in the answers of you guys, that's why i posted it here. But i am not the one down voted to your answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
select id from training where id not in ( select trainingid from record where userid = yourid)
```

Answer (score -1):

Get a list of users, cross join that with the training courses and then LEFT OUTER JOIN that to the table of training courses done by users. Us the WHERE clause to check there wasn't a match to the last table.

Untested, but something like this:-

```
SELECT sub_user.UserId, t.id
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT UserId from record
) sub_user
CROSS JOIN Training t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Record r
ON sub_user.UserId = r.UserId
AND r.trainingId = t.id
WHERE r.id IS NULL
```

If you have a table of users (which you probably do) then you could eliminate the sub query and replace it with that table.